# Use custom built Ckeditor5 in Vue3 with Vite

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, ckeditor, vite, quasar-framework

I'm Using Quasar and Vite with Vue3.
I wanted to add a **ckeditor** in my project but I need to have the **base64 upload adapter** to upload image.

I understood that I had to go on the online builder, select the features I wanted, download and use it.

I did those things, place that ckeditor5 folder next to my src/ folder.
I did `npm install ckeditor5/` to add that project into mine.

I also add ckedtor to boots files :

```js
import { boot } from "quasar/wrappers";
import CKEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue';

export default boot(({ app }) => {
  app.use(CKEditor);
});
```

And I finally tried to use it into a Vue component like this :

```js
<template>
    <ckeditor
        v-model="editorData"
        :editor="Editor"
        :config="editorConfig"
    />
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue";
import Editor from "ckeditor5-custom-build";
import ckeditor from "src/boot/ckeditor";

const editorData = ref("");
const editorConfig = ref({});

</script>
```

Note : the package name of the custom ckeditor is "ckeditor5-custom-build".
I followed everything on the ckeditor documentation.

But when the page is loaded, I get that error :
**SyntaxError: ambiguous indirect export: default**

I really don't understand what's wrong, I can't find any documentation on that. I tried using the classic editor and adding plugins but I got error : "duplicated-module" that's why I turned into the online builder

Do have any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

import * as CustomCkEditor from "ckeditor5-custom-build";

See if you can build with it.